# Why is there a Segmentation Fault from this vector code?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

When I execute this code in Code::Blocks I get a segmentation fault. Why? I've used debug and haven't found why. Any help is useful.

The debugger showed it was from the vector push_back method, but specifically on the "this" pointer used in the copy constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

const int MAX_COL = 7, MAX_ROW = 6;
const int NOPLAYER = 0, PLAYER1 = 1, PLAYER2 = 2;
const int NOTHING = 123;

int movesBeingStored = 0;
int movesCreated = 0;

class Move{
    public:
    Move() : row(-1), col(-1), plr(-1) {
        //std::cout << "Placed @" << col << "," << row << std::endl;
        ++movesBeingStored;
        ++movesCreated;
        std::cout << "+Now " << movesBeingStored << " move(s), Created " << movesCreated << std::endl;
    };
    Move(int r, int c, int p) : row(r), col(c), plr(p) {
        ++movesBeingStored;
        ++movesCreated;
        std::cout << "+Now " << movesBeingStored << " move(s), Created " << movesCreated << std::endl;
    };
    ~Move() {
        --movesBeingStored;
        std::cout << "-Now " << movesBeingStored << " move(s)" << std::endl;
    };
    int getRow() const { return row; }
    int getCol() const { return col; }
    int getPlayer() const { return plr; }

    Move(const Move* other) {
        ++movesBeingStored;
        ++movesCreated;
        std::cout << "+Now " << movesBeingStored << " move(s), Created " << movesCreated << std::endl;
        col = other->getCol();
        row = other->getRow();
        plr = other->getPlayer();
    }
    Move(const Move& other) {
        ++movesBeingStored;
        ++movesCreated;
        std::cout << "+Now " << movesBeingStored << " move(s), Created " << movesCreated << std::endl;
        col = other.getCol();   //This line causes a segment fault
        row = other.getRow();
        plr = other.getPlayer();
    }

    bool operator== (const Move& other) const {
        return (&other == this);
    }

    private:
    int row, col, plr;
};

int board[MAX_COL * MAX_ROW];
std::vector<Move> moves;
bool isFull[MAX_COL];
int tops[MAX_COL];
int currentPlayer = PLAYER1;
int checkedCollumns = 0;

void randomize( void ) { srand(time(NULL)); }
void startBoard( void );
void placeMove(int col, int player);
void popMove();
int checkwin(int curPlayer);
int checkMove(int depth, int& bestCol, int curP, int checkP);
int randomInt(int min, int max);
void printMoves( void );

int main()
{
    startBoard();
    randomize();
    int col = -1;
    int pts = checkMove(2, col, PLAYER1, PLAYER1);
    if(col == -1) {
        std::cout << "No best move" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Best move: Col " << col << std::endl;
        if(pts == NOTHING) {
            std::cout << "Nothing happens" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Gives " << pts << " points" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void startBoard( void ) {
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_COL; ++i) {
        isFull[i] = false;
        tops[i] = 0;
    }
    for(int p = 0; p < MAX_COL * MAX_ROW; ++p) {
        board[p] = NOPLAYER;
    }
}

void placeMove(int col, int player) {
    if(col < 0 || col >= MAX_COL)
        return;
    if(isFull[col])
        return;
    if(player != PLAYER1 && player != PLAYER2)
        player = PLAYER1;
    moves.push_back(Move(col, tops[col], player));
    board[col + tops[col] * MAX_COL] = player;
    ++tops[col];
    isFull[col] = (tops[col] == MAX_ROW);
}

void popMove() {
    if(moves.empty())
        return;
    Move move = moves.back();
    moves.pop_back();
    int col = move.getCol(), row = move.getRow();
    board[col + row * MAX_COL] = NOPLAYER;
    tops[col] = row;
    isFull[col] = (tops[col] == MAX_ROW);
}

int checkwin(int curPlayer) {
    if(randomInt(0,5) != 1)
        return NOTHING;
    return randomInt(0,4);
}

int checkMove(int depth, int& bestCol, int curP, int checkP) {
    int pts = NOTHING, col = -1, p = NOTHING, c = -1;
    if(depth <= 0) {
        if(moves.empty()) {
            bestCol = -1;
            return NOTHING;
        }
        Move move = moves.back();
        bestCol = move.getCol();
        pts = checkwin((move.getPlayer());
        if(move.getPlayer() != checkP && pts != NOTHING)
            pts = -pts;
        return pts;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_COL; ++i) {
        std::cout << "C: " << checkedCollumns;
        std::cout << "\tD: " << depth;
        std::cout << "\tM: " << moves.size();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        if(isFull[i])
            continue;
        ++checkedCollumns;
        placeMove(i, curP);
        p = checkMove(depth - 1, c, ((curP == PLAYER1)?PLAYER2:PLAYER1), checkP);
        popMove();
        if(p != NOTHING && checkP != curP)
            p = -p;
        if(col == -1) {
            col = i;
            pts = p;
            continue;
        }
        if(pts == NOTHING && p != NOTHING && p >= 0) {
            col = i;
            pts = p;
            continue;
        }
        if(pts != NOTHING && p != NOTHING && p > pts) {
            col = i;
            pts = p;
        }
    }
    bestCol = col;
    return pts;
}

int randomInt(int min, int max) {
    double per = (double)(rand() % RAND_MAX) / RAND_MAX;
    return min + (max - min) * per;
}

void printMoves( void ) {
    std::cout << "M:";
    if(moves.empty()) {
        std::cout << " --\t" << moves.size();
        return;
    }
    Move m;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < moves.size(); ++i) {
        m = moves.at(i);
        std::cout << " {" << m.getCol() << "," << m.getRow() << "}";
    }
    std::cout << "\t" << moves.size();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the call stack to see which of your functions triggers the call to push_back?

Comment: Why does `Move::operator==` compare pointer values?  It doesn't make sense, since you have an operator= that makes operator== counter-intuitive.

Comment: @TricksterTales - Here is what I mean:  `Move m1; Move m2; m2 = m1; if (m2 == m1) ... // What, not equal?? I just made them equal!`  See the issue?  I made m1 equal to m2, but then your code is now telling me that they're not equal.  That code would drive me nuts.

Comment: @TricksterTales You should be asking why it crashes only on the 64th iteration when movesCreated == 65. That's also the first time Move(const Move& other) seems to be used.

Comment: @TricksterTales On a sidenote, if you comment out those assignments and put all zeros, it also seems to run all the way to the end.
        col = 0;//other.getCol();   
        row = 0;//other.getRow();
        plr = 0;//other.getPlayer();

Comment: @MagikWorx The number created on iteration 64 would be much much higher than 64, because adding to the vector causes a creation into the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very trivial error, manifesting in a very obscure way. The segment fault is caused by the vector trying to construct an object at an invalid location. Why? Because of the following line in `void popMove()`:

```
board[col + row * MAX_COL] = NOPLAYER;
```

This line has a buffer overflow caused by invalid coordinates (0, 6), which overwrites the internal memory pointer in `moves`. That's the problem, the solution is up to you.

Comment: I should probably mention that the invalid coordinates seem to be caused by the `moves.push_back(Move(col, tops[col], player));` in `void placeMove(int col, int player)`. You probably meant to write `moves.push_back(Move(tops[col], col, player));`. I guess that's pretty much all the problem-solving you needed to do, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes, thank you for that note. I will try again and edit the top code to see if that was the problem or not

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem, it worked. Thank you, that was a stupid mistake of mine. Also, there was a parentheses missing but yeah, switched the arguments. Thanks again.